# If I owe state taxes, can the state seize a relative's property in retaliation?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, search-and-seizure, tax-law

I live in the United States and I owe taxes to the state, which I'm not able to pay. I don't have a permanent residence and live with family/friends.

One of my family members received a letter stating their property will be seized. They don't have any financial affiliation with me. Is it possible for the state to seize someone's property if I lived there — even though they have no financial affiliation with me?

Comment: Is this a personal income tax debt? Does it say it is seizing real estate or merely property located at a particular address belonging to you? Did you own it at any time in the past?

Answer (score 14):

The government cannot seize property because a person residing at that property has a tax debt: the debtor has to have a legal interest in the property, which you say you don't have. The government *can* seize property under the practice of civil forfeiture, which is a legal dispute between law enforcement and property – the simplest way to put it is that the property itself has "done wrong" (is involved in illegal activity). That's not what tax debt is.

It *is* possible for the state to seize property in error, so just because the state makes a mistake somehow does not mean that the state cannot file the paperwork and seize the property if the owners ignore the summons.

Comment: It's also possible that the impending property seizure doesn't relate to the OP at all, but instead is grounded in some other obligation owed by those who own the property. Seeing the letter (with personal info redacted) would help.

Comment: Could also just be a scam

Comment: And the family member could even be the scammer.

Comment: Lots of possible explanations for the letter. Address error; parcel number screw-up; prank...

Comment: hilmar it is not a scam. @DavidSupportsMonica no he is not a scammer. user6726 it is not a prank or scam. It is legitimate my name on the letter but with the address of the house. I don't own the house or ever have any financial dealings with the house whatsoever. The owner is all current on his taxes 100%. It just states that property is to be seized so if that is the case then is is that illegal for the state to do?

Comment: @Exocomp I don't see how. Even if I'm right, however, not taking action may cause things to get very much worse. Thus, you should consult with a lawyer _right now_ about this.

Comment: I know you think it is not a scam but you never know: scammers are much smarter than you'd think. I would stop by the town offices and ask them if there are really property taxes owed.  do not under any circumstances use any contact info on the letter.

Comment: @Exocomp: post a redacted image of the letter then.

Comment: In OP you say: "One of my family members received a letter ...", in comments to this ans you say: "... my name on the letter but with the address of the house".  If your name is on the letter, it wasn't one of your family members who received it.  It was sent to you - ergo it's your property they want to seize.  Would really help to see the letter.

Comment: @Exocomp The taxes owed may be public knowledge (if they're property taxes, for example, at least in IL, and many others are public also).  As such, this is *prime* candidate for scammers - they harvest unpaid tax amounts, guess at your address, and mail you a letter.  That aside, even if it's not public knowledge, if it's on your credit report there are still often ways for scammers or bill collectors to find that out; one common strategy is to call relatives and try to get them to pay something right then on the phone.

Comment: Sometimes tax debts can be collected in connection with an allegation proven at some point in some forum that the property was fraudulently transferred to the relative and is actually owned by the tax debtor, or that a tax lien attached before the property was transferred to the relative.

Comment: Also possible that the letter was directed to all tangible personal property you own at the best known address, and was sent to your best known address, and does not actually apply to the real property. Also possible that the tax authorities assume you own the house where you live and haven't done title work.